# how ot get Jmeter Websocket request body to file

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am using using following jmeter

i want to capture request body using Beanshell Listener for  HTTP request and WEBSOCKET

I am using following in BeanShell Listener

String data = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArgumens(0).getValue();
log.info("request message : " +data;

for HTTP request it is working fine but for Websocket it is not working

please help

to display request body in log.info

Answer (score 0):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) so consider migrating
2. The code you copied and pasted is relevant only for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, if you're using one of the WebSocket Samplers from [this plugin](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) you need to amend the function call a little bit:

   ```
   String data = sampler.getRequestData()
   ```